# textLabel alignment with accessoryview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

My UITableView text is center aligned. When I add in the accessory view, the alignment goes off. Trying to correct the frame doesn't work.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Don't "correct" the frame. Follow Holex's advice.

Answer (score 2):

My experience says the following.

The easiest way to control everything precisely in a `UITableViewCell` is to make a custom table view cell with custom accessories. It is a little bit more work but in this case you won't get any unwanted behaviour for your cell.

I'm not sure it helps you now but in the future you can avoid the headaches of the customised `UITableViewCell`.